# Python API requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am new to Python API, I am trying to retrieve data from an endpoint but I keep getting Error 400 bad request  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import requests 

payload = {
   "header" : {
    "cookie" :""
   },
    "body": {
        "email": "customer@****.com",
        "password": "****"
    }
}

headers = {
        'Host': 'https://ije-api.tcore.xyz',
        'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.18.0',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Referer': 'https://ije-api.tcore.xyz', 
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',

    }

request = requests.post("https://ije-api.tcore.xyz/v1/auth/login", json = payload, headers=headers)
print(request.text)
```

Comment: Make sure your endpoint is configured with HTTPS, otherwise you'll be sending a block of data that the endpoint cannot understand. A quick way to test this is to change `https` to `http` and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Also, you can use *postman* to test API.

Comment: You should understand the API and which parameters are required and which format is expected for those parameters. One mistake I see is that Referrer is mis-spelled in the headers. I'd advise removing any headers that arent neccessary and if you can get it to work, reintroduce them one by one until it breaks.

Comment: it is working in my postman but not working with my python requests -shaik

Comment: Thanks guys, It is working now